# How to match indexes from one list to another list and store values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, insert

I need help for my project.

Here is how it goes:

```
prod = [0, 5, 5]
dur = [5, 5, 3]
activity = [2, 3, 4]
max_r = 6
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to select an activity that follows these conditions:

```
max_prod = max(prod)

if max_prod <= max_r:

   # if yes and appears more than once, check dur, the activity with the highest duration will be put to select_act

   if prod.count(max_prod) > 1:

      # know the indexes of the values that appears more than once in prod
      idx = list_duplicates_of(prod, max_prod)

      # then get duration of these values
      dur_same = [d for a, d in zip(prod, dur) if a == max_prod]
      print(dur_same)

      #select the activity that has the highest duration
      #get dur of that selected activity

# if yes and appears only once, get activity and put in select_act
else:
    select_act = [activity[prod.index(max_prod)]]
    dur_select_act = [dur[prod.index(max_prod)]]
```

The problem is: `prod` has `3` indexes. If I were to do the code above, `max_prod` has `indexes 1 and 2` while when I try to print its `dur_same`, I get `[5, 3]` which do not match its supposed index in prod. How could I make sure/match the indexes of `dur_same` with its indexes in `prod` and just put `0` for the other index/es?

My expected output in that part should be:

```
prod = [0, 5, 5]
dur_same = [0, 5, 3] #instead  of just [5, 3] from the code above
```

In this way, it would be easier to call for its corresponding activity. Since all I have to do is to match the highest duration in `dur_same` with `dur` and get the index of the match in `dur`. Then, use this index to get the activity.

EDIT: 
If for instances that dur has the same highest value, let's say `dur_same = [0, 5, 5]`. How could I just choose randomly between the two 5s, then select its corresponding activity?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the list comprehension slightly to achieve this.

This is how you are doing it now:

```
In [1]: [d for a, d in zip(prod, dur) if a == max_prod]                                                                
Out[1]: [5, 3]
```

You change this to a one line if-else. If a == max_prod, it will add d to the list, else it will add 0.

```
In [2]: [d if a == max_prod else 0 for a, d in zip(prod, dur)]                                                         
Out[2]: [0, 5, 3]
```

Comment: I tried doing the code and it works perfectly. Just a follow up question, if you wouldn't mind, how could I call/select the activity that has the same index as the max in dur_same? So far, my code for that part looks like this: select_act = [d for a, d in zip(dur, activity) if a == max(dur_same)]. But this, matches max(dur_same) with dur and gets the activity. The thing is dur = [5, 5, 3] so the code calls for the two values of 5.